# Analytical continuations of partial sums

Tags: summation, analytic-continuation

Take a function $f(x) \in C^k(\mathbb{C})$ and consider the partial sum,
$$F(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n f(i), \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Is there a general method on how $F(n)$ can be extended to the real or complex plane?
At least, is there a sufficient and/or necessary condition on $f$ that ensures that resulting extension well-defined? For example, I would guess a necessary condition to be $k = \infty$?
As a simple (naive?) example, consider,
$$F(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n (n+1)}{2}.$$
Since we here have an explicit expression for the summation, it is quite straightforward to simply declare,
$$F(z) = \frac{z (z+1)}{2}, \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}.$$

Comment: Here is a trick you can use whenever the tail of $\sum_{i=1}^{N} f(i)$ can be approximated by a sequence of analytic functions $(g_N)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $\sup_{n\geq N} |F(n)-g_N(n)|\to 0$ for $N\to\infty$:

$$F(N+x) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} f(i) + \sum_{i=1}^{x} f(N+i)$$

$$F(x) = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{N} \left(f(i)-f(x+i)\right) + g_N(x)$$

Using this approach, you can for example obtain an analytic continuation for $f(x):=\ln(x)$ with $g_N(x):=x\ln(N)$ which yields an expression for $\ln(\Gamma)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, I would say that for starters you want some decay assumptions on $f$ for large n otherwise you'll have convergence issues.  But suppose $\lim_{n\to \infty} F(n)$ exits then you have a function defined on $\mathbb{N}$.  You certainly can extend it to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.  I'm  actually not sure you need any assumption for $f$ being differentiable to extend it to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$.  Now if we want to extend it to a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ I also don't see anything wrong with it.  You could take a sum of bump functions of height $f(n)$ with support $[n-\frac{1}{2},n-\frac{1}{2}]$.

As far as extending it to a complex analytic function, I also think you can do it but I can't think of a proof right now.

Hope this helps